# Method name expected with unityAction

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello I've got some problem. I know this is very easy problem for you but I cannot solve it.

```
public ItemList itemList;
UnityAction craft;
List<Item> items = new List<Item>();

void Start () {
    items = itemList.Items;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        craft = new UnityAction(itemList.Craft(items[i])); //There is a problem
        Transform child = transform.GetChild(i);
        child.GetChild(6).GetComponent<Button>().onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
        child.GetChild(6).GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(craft);
    }
}
```

Compiler says method name expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UnityAction` is a delegate:

```
public delegate void UnityAction();
```

So, in `ctor` you need pass a delegate. In your current snippter you are trying to call `Craft` method instead of passing delegate.

So, to resolve your problem you need just to write:

```
craft = new UnityAction(() => itemList.Craft(items[i]));
```

Another problem:
Due to labmda is invoked later, `for` loop may lead to undesired behaviours - I am almost sure, that all `Craft` calls will be invoked as

```
itemList.Craft(items[5])
```

because last value of `i` variable is `5` (after ending loop) - yes, that value is hold.
So, you need also to do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    var localI = i; // copying val to local scope
    craft = new UnityAction(() => itemList.Craft(items[localI]));
    // other
}
```